# Smoothing/interpolating NDVI to remove missing data and outliers

Tags: google-earth-engine, smoothing, spatial-outliers

I want to get the smooth NDVI data and want to remove the outliers, I want to know how can I achieve it. I attach my code, I tried to smooth it with 16 days window, but it still seems to have a sudden drop, missing data, and outliers.

```
var roi = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {"type": "rectangle"}
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[114.02880697101055, 22.492601725352458],
          [114.02880697101055, 22.489667540339862],
          [114.03172521441876, 22.489667540339862],
          [114.03172521441876, 22.492601725352458]]], null, false);
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MCD43A1")
                      .filterDate("2016-01-01", "2019-03-24")
function addNDVI(img) {
var ndvi = img.normalizedDifference(["BRDF_Albedo_Parameters_Band2_iso","BRDF_Albedo_Parameters_Band1_iso"]).rename('ndvi');
return img.addBands([ndvi]);
}
function clipImage(image) {
  return image.clip(roi);
}
var collection = collection.map(clipImage);

var collectionVI = collection.map(addNDVI);
var days = 16
var join = ee.Join.saveAll({
  matchesKey: 'images'
});
var diffFilter = ee.Filter.maxDifference({
  difference: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * days,
  leftField: 'system:time_start', 
  rightField: 'system:time_start'
});
var ndviCol = collectionVI.select('ndvi')
var joinedCollection = join.apply({
  primary: ndviCol, 
  secondary: ndviCol, 
  condition: diffFilter
});
var smoothedCollection = ee.ImageCollection(joinedCollection.map(function(image) {
  var collection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(image.get('images'));
  return ee.Image(image).addBands(collection.mean().rename('moving_average'));
}))
```